# How to do pagination, when the number of returned rows from sql is altered in php?

Tags: php, sql, pagination

I have a database with a books table and a persons table with around ~100k entries in each. A third table connects the two so they have a many-to-many relationship. Besides columns for book and person id, the connection table also has a column indicating the relation type between the book and the person, fx writer, co-writer or publisher or something else.

I need to make queries that return a list of all book entries with the persons related to them and the specific relation type. When joining the two tables, SQL returns multiple rows for books that have more than one person related to it, so I sort this out in php afterwards. The number of persons related to books varies from book to book with no predictable pattern.

I need to make a pagination system.

What would be the smartest way to do pagination in this situation?

Comment: are you paginating the books or the people?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention, I'm paginating the books.

Comment: I strongly suspect you'll have to select the books without joining the people so you can LIMIT correctly in your pagination and do a separate query to select the people.

Comment: Thanks! So a solution is to make two queries, one to count the books, and one that joins the tables and gets the info to populate the list?

Comment: yes. i've written it out in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all related persons per book in one row with `group_concat` and then paginate the result set with `limit offset, num_rows`

```
select b.book_id, b.title, ..., group_concat(c.type), group_concat(p.name)
from books b
join connections c on c.book_id = b.book_id
join persons p on p.person_id = c.person_id
group by book_id
limit 100, 50
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several alternatives, I'd say they can be sorted into two groups

1. you sent all rows and do the pagination in pure javascript (on the client side)
2. in addition to a limit you specify in your sql query you also specify an offset. That offset is stored inside your php session and incremented/decremented each time the user selects next/previous in your pagination.

Advantages / disadvantages:

1. one one single sql query per session, no additional http requests, since all is handled inside the client. The results visualized may be outdated when things change on the server side whilst looking at the result. The amount of rows transferred is bigger, so you have a longer loading time for the first visualization.
2. only those rows are queried and processed that are actually required for a single view. More rows are only retrieven upon request. The rows are always up to date, however things can get nasty if you work with offset values whilst the number of rows changes meanwhile (rare case). One http request per next/previous action, but a faster loading time for a single view.

---

For the problem of multiple hits for a single book because of the join:

I think you should follow a different strategy here:

1. either you use subqueries (a query inside a query), that way you can specify an offset and a limit to the inner query retrieving the books only without considerung the persons. Then the outer query joins the persons to the result of the inner query.
2. don't retrieve separate rows for multiple persons associated with book, but group those hits and join the persons maybe by concatenating their names or something. Like a set of persons in each book you retrieve. That way you have no problems specifying offset and limit.

Comment: I think the first issue is that left joining the people gives more than one result per book.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes the problem is, that I cannot use the LIMIT/OFFSET combination in SQL, since I have no way of predicting what value the OFFSET should be.

Comment: @krismeld: I can't follow you there. The value for offset depends on the session navigation only. You start with 0 (zero) and add a page size (say 20) for each 'next' action. Why can't you determine that? Note that the offset has nothing to do with the total number of hits you get from the database.

Comment: @popnoodles: I added a note to that problem too, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

You need to select your books **without** left joining the people so you can use LIMIT 0,20 for page 1, LIMIT 20,20 for page 2 etc for the pagination

Then  get the list of people for each book separately. You could use one SQL call per book or get them all for the books selected and fiddle with that list, whichever is quicker.

Answer (score 0):

It is terrible form, as you should most likely do as the previous answers have suggested - work within SQL.
However, you made the comment that you are sussing it all out in PHP.
That said, if you have all of your results in the script (i.e. not a huge database result), then it IS possible to handle it in PHP quite easily.

1. Store the result in a $_SESSION variable.
2. Count the result's length.
3. Divide the result by the number of items per page.
4. for loop through the result displaying the items for the first page.
5. build a link that passes the page number along with a query string or other means..
6. for loop through the results starting at the next item for the next page etc.

You might be interested in some of the custom functions provided on the [PHP.net manual page for count().](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)